# python - enter the correct number of variables based on function handle

Tags: python

I have a list of variables, and a function object and I would like to assign the correct number of variable depending on the function.

```
def sum2(x,y):
    return x + y

def sum3(x,y,z):
    return x + y + z

varList = [1,2,3]
```

so if f = sum2 , I would like it to call  first 2 elements of varList, and if f = sum3 , to call it with 3 elements of the function.

Comment: What do you mean by `f = sum2`? Are the two functions the same function in every aspect? Or do they contain different implementations for the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `inspect` module as follows:

```
import inspect
n2 = len(inspect.getargspec(sum2)[0])
n3 = len(inspect.getargspec(sum3)[0])
sum2(*varList[0:n2])
sum3(*varList[0:n3])
```

`getargspec` returns a 4-tuple of `(args, varargs, keywords, defaults)`. So the above code works if all your args are explicit, i.e. not * or ** args. If you have some of those, change the code accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a single function, if you are always returning the sum of all the passed arguments.

```
def sum1(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

This is just utilizing positional arguments, as you don't appear to need to explicitly set individual values. It is also most flexible than the solution provided by [ZdaR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598116/python-enter-the-correct-number-of-variables-based-on-function-handle/30598158#30598158), as you don't need to know ahead of time the maximum number of arguments you can receive.

Some examples:

```
>>> print sum1(1, 2, 3)
6
>>> print sum1(1)
1
>>> print sum1(-1, 0, 6, 10)
15
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use default initialization, You should keep in mind the maximum number of variables that could be passed to this function. Then create a function with that number of parameters but initializing them with 0, because `a+0 = a`(in case some parameters are missing it will replace then with `0` which won't affect the results.)

```
def sum1(a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0):
    return a+b+c+d

print sum1(1)
>>> 1

print sum1(1, 2)
>>> 3

print sum1(1, 2, 3)
>>> 6

print sum1(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> 10
```

However, if you call the function with more than 4 arguments, it would raise error statement

Also as suggested by @CoryKramer in the comments you can also pass your `varlist = [1, 2, 3, 4]` as a parameter :

```
print sum1(*varlist)
>>> 10
```

Keeping in mind that the `len(varlist)` should be less than the number of parameters defined.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution:

To get the number of argument, you can use f.func_code.co_argcount and than pass the correct elements from the list:

```py
def sum2(x,y):
    return x + y

def sum3(x,y,z):
    return x + y + z

varlist = [2,5,4]


[f(*varlist[:f.func_code.co_argcount]) for f in [sum2,sum3]]

>> [7, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if f is a function with the `is` keyword

```
def sum2(x, y):
    return x + y

def sum3(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z

varList = [1, 2, 3]

f = sum2

if f is sum2:
    sum = f(varList[0], varList[1])
    print('Sum 2: ' + str(sum))
    # Prints: 'Sum 2: 3'


f = sum3

if f is sum3:
    sum = f(varList[0], varList[1], varList[2])
    print('Sum 3: ' + str(sum))
    # Prints: 'Sum 3: 6'
```

Answer (score 0):

A dict of functions:

```
def two(l):
    return l[0] + l[1]

def three(l):
    return l[0] * l[1] + l[2]

funcs = {2:two, 3:three}

l = [1, 2, 3]

print len(l)

print funcs[len(l)](l)
```